# Reduce voltage and current in dc circut

Tags: voltage, voltage-divider, amperage

Amateur electro hobbyist here. What can I use to drop both voltage and amps in my circut? I need to drop 19V 2.1A (power source) to 12V 0.8A. I got a bunch of resistors

Comment: The current is determined by the the load so really its how do you get from 19V to 12V efficiently - buck converter.

Comment: voltage divider if you only have resistors.  Current can be controlled via a series resistor or simply by the impedance of the load.

Answer (score 1):

If this is a power supply (and not some signal within your circuit.) Then you could use a linear three terminal regulator, [like the 7812](https://www.fairchildsemi.com/datasheets/LM/LM7805.pdf) But you will need a big heat sink... ~6 Watts or so.  They also no make switch mode DC-DC converters, like one of [these](http://www.cui.com/product/resource/v78xx-1000.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

> I need to drop 19V 2.1A (power source) to 12V 0.8A

I expect that you really mean "I have a 19 volt power source that is capable of delivering 2.1 amps and my target load requires 12 volts at a maximum current of 0.8 amps".

A really efficient switching buck converter is this: -

[image]

If you want something cheaper and less good on performance then ebay sell dozens of buck converters already packaged up on a circuit board.